# Java Switch between cases without every time skipping the remaining cases

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am new to Java, would appreciate some help.
what I am trying to do here is switch between the cases. However what I also need is to not skip the remaining cases in this procedure.

I mean the code below should output:
two
four
three
four

```
public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = "two";
        while(true)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case "zero":
                {
                    System.out.println("zero");
                    n="one";
                }
                case "one":
                {
                    System.out.println("one");
                    n="three";
                }
                case "two":
                {
                    System.out.println("two");
                    if (12>3)
                    {
                        n="four";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                case "three":
                {
                    System.out.println("three");
                }
                case "four":
                {
                    System.out.println("four");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have used return to end the while loop. Now I do understand that I have used break in case two which will break the current switch and thereby not complete it. But if i don't, I just can't switch between cases in the first place. So, I need a different solution. And working implementation in java should be helpful. Thanks

Comment: In your sample `two four three four` how do you plan to differentiate between the first `four` and the second? Why does the second `four` terminate and the first `four` continues with `three`?

Comment: And in addition to what Izruo already asked: why should "three" continue with "four"?

Comment: @Tom That's simple: `three` might always continue with `four`. At least it is what the code provided actually does.

Comment: the first "four" is printed when the the case gets passed from case two, and then the second four gets printed when case two condition ends and and further goes ahead to case three and then four

Comment: and yes, the implemented code of mine doesn't satisfy what i need it to do and so is wrong I guess

Comment: Sadly, that's no condition you can evaluate with a simple `switch` statement. It can only evaluate the value it is currently 'switiching' over.

Comment: that's why I suggested some different approach. thanks for such quick replies though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Queue` for this.
Each case is responsible to add the next one to the queue by the order of expected execution.

```
Queue q = new LinkedList();
q.add("two");
String n = (String)q.poll();
while(n!=null)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case "zero":
        {
            System.out.println("zero");
            q.add("one");
            break;
        }
        case "one":
        {
            System.out.println("one");
            q.add("three");
            q.add("two");
            break;
        }
        case "two":
        {
            System.out.println("two");
            if (12>3)
            {
                q.add("four");

            }

             q.add("three");
             break;
        }
        case "three":
        {
            System.out.println("three");
            q.add("four");
            break;
        }
        case "four":
        {
            System.out.println("four");
            break;
        }
    }
    n=(String) q.poll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not lie within the switch statement. You simply need to distinguish from where you 'came from'.

To do that you need to remember it, e.g. in a local variable:

```
String lastN;
```

and in the loop before the switch:

```
lastN = n;
```

Now you can do something like:

```
case "four":
    {
        System.out.println("four");
        if("three".equals(lastN))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            n = "three";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry earlier didn't check your edited solution. This solution works, however is there any method to know which case come after one, I mean in order. I mean, suppose there are multiple cases which are directed towards a same case, I can't then direct the switch to some fixed case.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as it should, if what you need is a [fall through](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)
then consider the fact that case **zero** and **one** must be executed first...

on the other hand, you don't need to add  **{ }** to the case group

```
case "zero": {
    System.out.println("zero");
    n = "one";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = "two";
        while(true)
        {
            switch (n)
            {
                case "zero":
                {
                    System.out.println("zero");
                }
                case "one":
                {
                    System.out.println("one");
                }
                case "two":
                {
                    System.out.println("two");
                }
                case "four":
                {
                    System.out.println("four");
                    if(n=="four"){
                        return;
                    }
                }
                case "three":
                {
                    System.out.println("three");
                    n="four";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please present some explanation.

Comment: The first while loop, n="two"，switch case "two"，if there is no break，then it would Continue to execute the following statement without judge the remaining case,until it encounter the case again or complete the entire switch